# Android Studio - Embedded JDK - Execution failed

Tags: android

So I just downloaded the lastest version of Android Studio (2.2.2). And I get this error when Run an emulator:
[image: error_image]

I searched and found it has something to do with JDK path, so I tried the non embedded one but still no result.
My setting for Project Structure is (embedded path):

[image: embedded_path]

Non-embedded path:

[image]

Perhaps my path is wrong? What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying `build failed` , so I guess the error with your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`.

Try changing something like this (in app level gradle file):

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

**NOTE:** Both should be in same version. For example if you are choosing `compileSdkVersion` 22 then choose `buildToolVersion` as something like 22.0.1 or 22.0.2 or something that you have installed. Try versions and Android Studio will tell you if the version is installed or not

Comment: Mine was compileSdkVersion 24, buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" so I changed to buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" and restarted Android Studio, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file here? @VuN.

Comment: I'm not sure which one, so here are 2 of mine: 1 for app, 1 for my application name.
https://gyazo.com/1f364ae905c0426f787849c500b67006
https://gyazo.com/4122fd5366d65d32b717088781302861

Comment: Solve errors so that the red line shown below some dependencies get disappear and you will see a "sync now" button popping up the main page when you will change something in it (build.gradle(app)). Sync that and make sure no errors are showing now @VuN.